# Duplicate a row and change one of the duplicated values based on previous row

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have my code duplicate the last instance of the row, duplicating also the values inside them, [interface now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlUY4.png)
,but what i need is for the time value in heure_fin of the previous row to be duplicated into the heure_debut column, and for the heure_fin of the duplicated row to have +1 hour of the time in the heure_debut column and for it to keep going like this each time it is duplicated [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8We9.png).

```
   <div class="card-body pt-0">

    <table class="table align-middle table-row-dashed fs-6 gy-5"  id='tbl'>

     <thead>

      <tr class="text-start text-gray-400 fw-bolder fs-7 text-uppercase gs-0">
        <th class="min-w-200px">date</th>
        <th class="min-w-200px">heure début</th>
        <th class="min-w-200px">heure fin</th>
        <th class="min-w-200px">Process</th>
        <th class="min-w-200px">Personne</th>
      </tr>

     </thead>

            <tbody  id="tbody">


                <tr class="fw-bold text-gray-600" >

                    <td>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">

                            <div class="ms-5">

                                <div class="error-container">
                                <input style="width: 60%" required class="form-control datecalendar" name="date[]" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" id="kt_calendar_datepicker_start_date" />
                                @if ($errors->has('date'))
                                            <small id="name-error" class="has-error help-block help-block-error">{{ $errors->first('date') }}</small>
                                            @endif

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-items-center">
                    <div class="error-container">
                        <span class="fw-bolder"><input style="width: 40%" name="heure_debut[]" placeholder="HH:MM" id="time_picker_change" required class="form-control" /></span>
                        @if ($errors->has('heure_début'))
                                            <small id="name-error" class="has-error help-block help-block-error">{{ $errors->first('heure_début') }}</small>
                                            @endif
                                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-items-center">
                        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('heure_fin') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div class="error-container">
                                <span class="fw-bolder"><input style="width: 40%" required class="form-control" placeholder="HH:MM" name="heure_fin[]" id="time_picker_change" /></span>
                                @if ($errors->has('heure_fin'))
                                                <small id="name-error" class="has-error help-block help-block-error"><p class="text-danger">heure fin doit être forcément supérieure a heure début</p></small>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>


                    <td class="align-items-center">
                        <span class="fw-bolder">
                    
                            <select name="process_id[]" id="process_id" required class="form-select form-select-solid" data-kt-select2="true" data-placeholder="choisissez un standard">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>processus</option>
                                    @foreach ($process as $key => $proc)
                                        <option value="{{ $proc->id }}">{{ $proc->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select></span>

                    </td>

                    <td class="align-items-center">
                        <span class="fw-bolder "><select name="user_id[]" id="user_id" required class="form-select form-select-solid" data-kt-select2="true" data-placeholder="choisissez une ressource/personne">
                                <option value="" disabled selected>nom</option>
                                @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
                                    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select></span>
                    </td>


                </tr>


            </tbody>

        </table>
        
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Ajouter ligne">
        <input type="button" id="btndelete"  class="btn btn-primary" value="Supprimer ligne">

    </div>
```

script:

```
   $("#btnAdd").on("click",function(){ var $tableBody = $('#tbl').find("tbody"),

           $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
           $trNew = $trLast.clone();
           
       $trLast.after($trNew);
   });

   $("#btndelete").on("click",function(){
   
   var $tableBody = $('#tbl').find("tbody"),
           $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),
           $trNew = $trLast.remove();
           
       $trLast.after($trNew);
   });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... so what problem are you having?

Comment: @lagbox the code right now duplicates exactly what was in the previous line. What i need instead is when i duplicate it, the value in heure_fin that is being duplicated, to be put in the heure_debut and for the heure_fin of that row to be the heure_debut +1 (basically if the time of heure_fin is 13:30 , the heure_debut of it duplicate will become 13:30 and the heure_fin will be 14:30, and for it to keep cycling like that each time it is duplicated taking the last row into consideration ). thanks for your time.

Comment: what problem are you having accomplishing that?

Comment: so far i've tried to duplicate each column individually so that i could change the value of the desired columns, but then they get duplicated on the same row and i still can't get the values to be passed over to the duplicates the way i want, so what i would like to know is how to go about things to achieve my desired result since i don't know the exact way of doing so.